# OAuthException from LogicApp to Facebook - LogicApp design

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-logic-apps

this morning I'm doing my first Azure LogicApp with the target to write a post to my facebook page.

When I connect to FB with my account I don't have any problem, but when I run the logic app the problem:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "BEJRLPWccrI"
  }
}
```

I'm the admin (and creator) of the related page.

**Error**

[image]

Comment: I'm running in to the same problem and same error.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586901/cant-post-to-owned-fb-page-with-app-in-developer-mode-using-api 
It win't work with the logic app, nor with API directly use FB graph API Explorer.  I don't know why.  Permissions are fine.  As per documentation this should work in developer mode.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have recently (Effective August 2018) [changed their permissions model](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/group) and have disabled the publication to facebook from external apis. There is a similar thread going on [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df752944-d297-41ab-8891-ef4158644527/why-condition-failed-to-post-on-facebook-using-azure-logic-apps?forum=azurelogicapps).

Comment: That should impact published apps.  This app is still a development app, so this should work.